# VPN server inside of a Strato vServer

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vpn

I have a [Strato vServer](https://www.strato.de/server/linux-vserver/) with a Ubuntu 18 OS running on it and I try to install a VPN server on this Server by using [this](https://gridscale.io/community/tutorials/openvpn-ubuntu-installieren/) guide. But I got the following error message after running `service openvpn@server restart`:

```
Aug  6 23:39:19 systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN connection to server.
Aug  6 23:39:19 ovpn-server[31964]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Aug  6 23:39:19 ovpn-server[31964]: Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Aug  6 23:39:19 ovpn-server[31964]: Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Aug  6 23:39:19 ovpn-server[31964]: TUN/TAP device tap0 opened
Aug  6 23:39:19 ovpn-server[31964]: Note: Cannot set tx queue length on tap0: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Aug  6 23:39:19 ovpn-server[31964]: do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Aug  6 23:39:19 ovpn-server[31964]: /sbin/ip link set dev tap0 up mtu 1500
Aug  6 23:39:19 ovpn-server[31964]: openvpn_execve: unable to fork: Resource temporarily unavailable (errno=11)
Aug  6 23:39:19 ovpn-server[31964]: Exiting due to fatal error
Aug  6 23:39:19 systemd-udevd[31965]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Aug  6 23:39:19 systemd-udevd[31965]: link_config: could not get ethtool features for tap0
Aug  6 23:39:19 systemd-udevd[31965]: Could not set offload features of tap0: No such device
Aug  6 23:39:19 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug  6 23:39:19 systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So it seems that `tap0` doesn´t exist. But why is it missing and how can I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about the `LimitNPROC` setting. You get the current value with

```
systemctl show openvpn@server --property=LimitNPROC
```

You can fix the problem by adding this to the unit file

```
[Service]
LimitNPROC=infinity
```

and then run `systemctl daemon-reload` before you restart the OpenVPN service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What "unit" file do you mean?

Comment: @Kampi I mean the file given by `systemctl cat openvpn@server.service | head -n 1`. If that is not in `/etc/systemd/system` then copy it to that directory and edit the copy. The files in `/etc` have precedence over those in `/usr`.